# I want to count number of points inside the given shape

Tags: regions, random

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {1000, 2}];
ParametricPlot[{{2 r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {r Cos[t], 2 r Sin[t]}}, {t, 
  0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}, Mesh -> False, Epilog -> {Blue, Point[data]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {1000, 2}];

r1 = ParametricRegion[{2 r Cos[t], 
   r Sin[t]}, {{t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 1}}]
r2 = ParametricRegion[{r Cos[t], 
   2 r Sin[t]}, {{t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 1}}]
RegionQ /@ {r1, r2}
```

> {True, True}

```
pts1 = Select[data, RegionMember[r1]];
pts2 = Select[data, RegionMember[r2]]
pts3 = Select[data, RegionMember[RegionIntersection[r1, r2]]];

Length /@ {pts1, pts2, pts3}
```

> {406, 395, 252}

Visualization:

```
rplot1 = RegionPlot[{r1, r2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];
p1 = ListPlot[pts1, PlotStyle -> Black];
p2 = ListPlot[pts2, PlotStyle -> Darker@Green];
p3 = ListPlot[pts3, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[rplot1, p1, p2, p3]
```

[image]

Comment: In final output i want to find the area of this shape by Monte Carlo random method.Also to create animation from Modulate syntax.Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: @61-SaiyedUvais Please start a fresh post and describe what you want. Investigate `RandomPoint` as a first step. Thanks for the accept.

Comment: First we are throwing random dots in our shape which is kept in a rectangular frame .Then i want count number of point which are inside  and outside the shape.Then j want to find area of shape from monte Carlo estimation.Formula for approximately area = (points inside the shape)/(points outside the shape) *area of rectangle.In last i want animation for our project which is given by "Modulate" syntax

Comment: I assume you meant `Manipulate`. Is the intent to alter the region boundaries, or the points? If (as I expect) the boundaries, this can be slow to compute and you'll need to carefully consider how to go about it in anything remotely approaching "real time". If instead you want to animate separate Monte Carlo area estimates for the same shape, but using different point sets, that might be easier to make fast.

Comment: How can i show dots outside our shape and how to count it.

Comment: Please take a look at `RegionUnion` and `Complement` in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

With the following test data:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {1000, 2}];
```

You may define a region using `ParametricRegion`:

```
pr = ParametricRegion[{2 r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {{t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}}];
```

Then you may test if a point is inside the region using `RegionMember`in its operator form:

```
RegionMember[pr] /@ data
```

This replaces every point by True if the point  is inside the region, False otherwise. Finally you may count how many "True" there are:

```
Count[RegionMember[pr] /@ data, True]
(* 406 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

This exploits the simple nature of the regions and uses [`RegionMember`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html):

```
   func[n_] := Module[{pts = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {n, 2}],
   r1 = Disk[{0, 0}, {2, 1}],
   r2 = Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 2}], int, rf, gb, lp},
  int = RegionIntersection[r1, r2];
  rf[{x_, y_}] := RegionMember[int, {x, y}];
  gb = KeySort@GroupBy[pts, rf];
  lp = ListPlot[gb, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}];
  Column[{
    Show[lp, 
     ParametricPlot[{{2 Cos[t], Sin[t]}, { Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}}, {t, 0, 
       2 Pi}], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
     PlotLabel -> Row[{"n=", n}]],
    Grid[{{"Test", rf[{x, y}]},
      {"Montecarlo Area", 16. #2/(#1 + #2) & @@ Length /@ gb},
      {"Analytic area", RegionMeasure[int, 2] // N}}]}]]
```

Simulating for sample sizes: {10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000}:

[image]